# For in loop wont is stuck at variable (class in this case) Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I cant found why the for (class) in (list) loop is stuck at the first element of the list it wont go further, there is no error output. When execute in with the debugger on, we can see that it only loop once and skip the rest.

```
# print(self.APPLICATION.WALLS) output: 4

for wall in self.APPLICATION.WALLS: # loop once and stop there
     if wall.ISVERTICALE:
         x_intersect = wall.START_X_POSITION
         y_intersect = (amplitude * x_intersect) + height
         y_positions = list(wall.START_Y_POSITION, wall.END_Y_POSITION).sort()

     if y_positions[0] < y_intersect < y_positions[1]:
         if list(x_position, x_intersect, self.x_position).sort()[1] == x_intersect:
             return True
         return False
     return False
     if wall.ISHORIZONTAL:
         y_intersect = wall.START_Y_POSITION
         x_intersect = (y_intersect - height) /  amplitude
         return False
```

Comment: It's because of you `return False` just before `wall.ISHORIZONTAL`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's hitting `return`, returning the value to the caller and ending the function.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this code. `list(x, y)` is not equivalent to `[x, y]`. `sort` does not return any useful value; it sorts the invoking list in-place. `self.APPLICATION.WALLS`, according to the commented call to `print`, does not even appear to be an iterable value. It's not clear how this code executes *anything* without an error.